# Get SetMeUp token API

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I want to know the api endpoint where I can post username and password and that should return me the auth token. For more clarity I am attaching the screenshot.

[image]

I know it's making call to following endpoint but these endpoint are not having any documentation, maybe they are not public.

https://containerimages.azz.net/artifactory/ui/userProfile

https://containerimages.azz.net/artifactory/ui/userApiKey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APIs you mention in the question are UI APIs. Those are not public and might be a subject to change. You should rely on them.

If you wish to generate a Docker `config.json` file as the one shown in the screenshot, the `auth` part is simply a base64 encoding of the `<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>`.
For the  part use can use:

1. An [access token](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/ACC/Access+Tokens) - this is the preferred method as tokens are revokable an expirable
2. [API Key](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Updating+Your+Profile#UpdatingYourProfile-APIKey)
3. [Encrypted password](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Centrally+Secure+Passwords)
4. Clear text password

All options should be base64 encoded as mentioned above.

You can avoid storing the Docker credentials in the `config.json` file by using a credentials store as described in the [Docker login documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/).

If you wish to get an Artifactory API key for a user, you should use the [Get API Key](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetAPIKey) REST API.

Comment: Is there any other way I don't want to store username and password just plaintext base64 conversion?

Comment: @prashant I updated the answer with some recommendations